# UIScrollView: Show user profile Images in a scroll view when user name is called from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiscrollview

I'm building an app in which a user answers questions with a selection of 4 random users they are following. Currently it calls random names from my firebase database. Each user has a profile image they upload when signing up and this is saved in the same place as the users fullname.

I would like the profile image to be called at the same time as the fullnames and shown on the UIScrollView of the screen in the order that the names are called (e.g. so option A user image is shown first, then scroll to option B user Image etc) - [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhxMt.png)

So far, the fullnames are being called and shown on the button and I can access the firebase storage for the URL but I don't know how to get the profileImageUrl from firebase to show in this order on the scrollview when the users names are picked randomly, so far i have this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pinionImagesScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var optionA: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionC: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionD: UIButton!

        let numberOfKeys = randomKeyArray.count
        var namesRemaining = numberOfKeys
        var names = [String]()
        var profileImages = [String]()

        for i in 0..<numberOfKeys {
            let thisUserKey = randomKeyArray[i]
            let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
                let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String
                print(name)
                namesRemaining -= 1
                names.append(name)

                // Another array for images
                print(profileImageUrl)
                profileImages.append(profileImageUrl)

                self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)
                if namesRemaining == 0 {
                    self.currNames = names
                    self.optionA.setTitle(names[0], for: .normal)
                    self.optionA.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                    self.optionB.setTitle(names[1], for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                    self.optionC.setTitle(names[2], for: .normal)
                    self.optionC.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                    self.optionD.setTitle(names[3], for: .normal)
                    self.optionD.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                }
            })
        }
```

Would appreciate any help/explanation, thanks :)

EDIT update of code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imagePageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var userImageScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var optionA: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionC: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionD: UIButton!

var user: UserModel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadNewQuestion()
    getFourRandomNodesAndPrintUserName()
    imagePageControl.numberOfPages = namesWithUrl.count
    setupLayout()
}


var ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
var currNames: [String] = []
var currIds: [String] = []
var names = [String]()
var namesWithUrl = [String : String]()
var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
var imageViewA = UIImageView()
var imageViewB = UIImageView()
var imageViewC = UIImageView()
var imageViewD = UIImageView()

func setupLayout() {

    userImageScrollView.addSubview(imageViewA)
    imageViewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageViewA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    imageViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

    userImageScrollView.addSubview(imageViewB)
    imageViewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageViewB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    imageViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewA.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

    userImageScrollView.addSubview(imageViewC)
    imageViewC.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageViewC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    imageViewC.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageViewC.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewB.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

    userImageScrollView.addSubview(imageViewD)
    imageViewD.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageViewD.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    imageViewD.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageViewD.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewC.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    imageViewD.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
}

   // Each view is attached to the bottom of the previous view, and the final must be attached to the bottom of the scroll view in order for it to scroll properly.

func getFourRandomNodesAndPrintUserName() {
    self.currNames = []
    self.currIds = []

    var myKeyArray = [String]()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let ref = self.ref.child("following").child(uid)
    //retreives all nodes in the following node
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.children.allObjects)
        for child in snapshot.children { //build the array of keys
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            myKeyArray.append(key)
        }

        var randomKeyArray = [String]()
        let numFollowers = min(4, myKeyArray.count)
        for _ in 0..<numFollowers { //will iterate four times
            let count = myKeyArray.count //get the number of elements
            let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<count) //get a random index for the array
            let randomUserKey = myKeyArray[randomInt]
            randomKeyArray.append(randomUserKey)
            myKeyArray.remove(at: randomInt) //remove that object so it's not selected again
        }

        let numberOfKeys = randomKeyArray.count

        var namesRemaining = numberOfKeys

        for i in 0..<numberOfKeys {
            let thisUserKey = randomKeyArray[i]
            let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
                let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String

                print(name)
                print(profileImageUrl)
                namesRemaining -= 1
                self.names.append(name)
                self.namesWithUrl[name] = profileImageUrl


                self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)

                if numFollowers <= 3 {
                    self.optionA.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionA.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
                    self.optionA.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
                    self.optionA.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionB.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
                    self.optionB.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionC.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionC.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
                    self.optionC.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
                    self.optionC.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionD.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionD.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
                    self.optionD.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
                    self.optionD.isEnabled = false
                }
                else if namesRemaining == 0 {
                    self.currNames = self.names
                    self.optionA.setTitle(self.names[0], for: .normal)
                    self.optionA.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                    self.imageViewA.sd_setImageLoad(URL(namesWithUrl[name[0]])) //this is where i am getting the error - here you want to set the image to the imageView not the scrollView

                    self.optionB.setTitle(self.names[1], for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

                    self.optionC.setTitle(self.names[2], for: .normal)
                    self.optionC.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                    self.optionD.setTitle(self.names[3], for: .normal)
                    self.optionD.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                }
                self.userImageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (self.userImageScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(self.namesWithUrl.count)), height: self.userImageScrollView.frame.size.height)
                self.userImageScrollView.delegate = self
            })
        }
    })
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = userImageScrollView.contentOffset.x / userImageScrollView.frame.size.width
    imagePageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

Update: how it looks

[how images look now instead of being able to swipe between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKTJ7.png)

EDIT: Trying to make it so you can swipe between the images - but am getting error: Thread 1 SIGBART on app delegate

```
var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

func setupLayout() {
    frame.origin.x = userImageScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(4)
    frame.size = userImageScrollView.frame.size

    let imageViewA = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    userImageScrollView.addSubview(self.imageViewA)

    imageViewA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true


    let imageViewB = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    userImageScrollView.addSubview(self.imageViewB)

    imageViewB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    imageViewB.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewA.leftAnchor)

    let imageViewC = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    userImageScrollView.addSubview(imageViewC)

    imageViewC.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    imageViewC.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewB.leftAnchor)

    let imageViewD = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    userImageScrollView.addSubview(imageViewD)

    imageViewD.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    imageViewD.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewC.leftAnchor)

    self.userImageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (self.userImageScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(4)), height: self.userImageScrollView.frame.size.height)
    self.userImageScrollView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: If i understand, you want to do something like `self.optionAimageView.image =` with the `profileImageUrl[0]` and so on right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a dictionary of `names:profileImageUrl`

```
var namesWithUrl = [String : String]()
```

and instead of just `names.append(name)` do:

```
names.append(name)
namesWithUrl[name] = profileImageUrl
```

so now the name is held in a dictionary with its correct profileImageUrl and so the dictionary will look like:

```
[name1value : name1URl, name2value : name2URl, ...]
```

Then if you use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) you can do this very simply:

```
self.optionA.setTitle(names, for: .normal)
self.optionA.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
self.optionA.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: URL(namesWithUrl[name[1]]), for: .normal)
//If using the button image

self.optionB.setTitle(names[1], for: .normal)
self.optionB.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
optionAImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(namesWithUrl[name[1]]))
//if using a seperate imageView
```

That will easily set the image to your imageView, and you can just add that line under each one.

EDIT: Adding image views to scroll view.

You can add the image view through the storyboard, onto the scroll view or you can add them programmatically like so:

First declare them:

```
var imageViewA = UIImageView()
var imageViewB = UIImageView()
```

Then I like to have a setupLayout function to handle my views:

```
func setupLayout() {

pinionImagesScrollView.addsubview(imageViewA)
imageViewA.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageViewA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinionImagesScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
imageViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
imageViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinionImagesScrollView.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

pinionImagesScrollView.addsubview(imageViewA)
imageViewB.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageViewB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinionImagesScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
imageViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
imageViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewA.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

}
```

There you can see how we are putting the imageViewB below imageViewA and the width is the same as the scrollview -10 giving a bit of space.

then call `setupLayout()` in `viewDidLoad()`. they will be empty until you place the images on them. with `optionAImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(namesWithUrl[name[1]]))`

Update:

You may need to change the String version of the url into a URL for SD_setimage like so:

```
 let optionAUrl = URL.init(string: nameUrls[names[0]])
  imageView.sd_setImage(with: optionAUrl)
```

The subscript error may mean you are initializing the dictionary wrong as I have tested and it should work fine.

Update:

The problem with you setupLayout is you are mixing auto layout with using frames. I assume your scrollViews constraints are defined in storyboard so Here is how you would set up the imageViews, so that the width and height are the same as the scrollView, and you can scroll between them. Note if you would like to scroll horizontally, you should research about using a UICollectionView instead.

In this example I am creating the scrollView programatically, you can just focus on the imageViews as your constraints are made in storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let imageViewA = UIImageView()
let imageViewB = UIImageView()
let imageViewC = UIImageView()
//Declaring the imageViews

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupLayout()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func setupLayout() {
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .gray
    //setting up the size of the scrollView

    scrollView.addSubview(imageViewA)
    //This means we are using autoLayout, building the views and setting their size based on how their constraints relate to other objects
    imageViewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    //Setting the imageViewA top anchor to the scrollView topanchor we are essentially saying the top of this imageView starts at the top of the scroll view
    imageViewA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    //Here the imageViews width is equal to the scrollViews width, (-10 is optional if you want it not to touch the edges)
    imageViewA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
     //CenterXAnchor here I am making sure the imageView is centered in the scrollView
    imageViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
     //same with the height
    imageViewA.backgroundColor = .cyan
     //Background just for my testing as I dont have any images to sue
    imageViewA.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
     //This is how you want the image to scale into the view for when you set it.
    scrollView.addSubview(imageViewB)
    imageViewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewA.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    //Because we want to scroll down, the top anchor of imageViewB is equal to the bottom anchor of imageViewA meaning the top of B starts at the bottom of A
    imageViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
   imageViewB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    //Height and widths are the same.
    imageViewB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageViewB.backgroundColor = .cyan
    imageViewB.contentMode = scaleAspectFit
    scrollView.addSubview(imageViewC)
    imageViewC.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageViewC.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewB.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    //imageViewCs top starts at bottom of B
    imageViewC.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageViewC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    imageViewC.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageViewC.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
     //for the final view, it needs to be connected to the bottom so the scrollView is able to scroll.
    imageViewC.backgroundColor = .cyan
    imageViewC.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}


}
```

This gives me a square Scrollview, which shows the imageViewA and allows me to scroll down and see imageViewB and then imageView C

Output of this code, scrollView is set to centerYanchor of view so it stops at the middle, blue squares are imageViews, image1 shows how it starts you can see ImageViewA, then image2 shows how you can scroll to the next image: [image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Right now, I have a UIScrollView on top of the page and it's not connected to the UIButtons - should I change it to a UIImageView? I haven't figured out which one would allow me to connect the button to the image so it can handle the 4 profile images - really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Because i'm getting 2 errors on the sd_setImage(with: URL.... line The 1st is: 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion and the 2nd is: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Character'

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of how your interface looks, you have the buttons with the 4 names, and then a scrollview with the images on it?

Comment: @edey I see its in your question, Let me have a think.

Comment: @edey if you want to have the 4 images in the scrollView I assume starting with optionA at the top, then youi need 4 imageViews inside the scrollView, imageViewA, ImageViewB etc, then `imageViewA.sd_setimage` should work. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean (sorry for the delayed reply) - how can I add the 4 imageViews inside the scrollView like that? Would I have to add an imageView inside the scroll view on the story board first then connect it? Thank you so much

Comment: I've updated the question for you, you can place them in on the storyboard or check the update if you want to do it programmatically.

Comment: I'm still getting the error: "'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion" and "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Character'" for the final line with the sd_setImage - l get an error which updates to sd_setImageLoad(URL(namesWithUrl[name[0]]), forKey: <#String?#>)

Comment: @edey Okay I'll have a look now and see what the problem is

Comment: @edey code should work, can you update your question will the full code as it is now?

Comment: Just updated with the edits - i'll try your update now too :)

Comment: with `self.userImageScrollView.sd_setImageLoad(URL(namesWithUrl[name[0]]), forKey: <#String?#>)`  there doesnt need to be `forKey: <#String?#>` make sure when you are doing .sd_setImage if anything pops up try instead of selecting just typing `.sd_setImage(with optionAUrl) also, you should be doing `self.imageVIewA.sd_setImage` as you want the first imageVIew inthe scroll view for option A

Comment: @edey check if you can see my edits to your question, I fixed some of the constraints for your imageViews as you will run into problems with them. But so far doing `let optionAUrl = URL.init(string: nameUrls[names[0]])` and then
  `imageViewA.sd_setImage(with: optionAUrl)` should work.

Comment: in order to change the string version of the URL would i need to replace "self.namesWithUrl[name] = profileImageUrl" with " let optionAUrl = URL.init(string: nameUrls[names[0]])
  imageView.sd_setImage(with: optionAUrl)" etc?

Comment: @eday no, just before you do sd_setImage you make a new variable which takes the String from namesWithUrl[name] and turns it into a URL with `let optionAURL = URL.init(string: namesWithUrl[names[0]]` because `profileImageUrl` is actually a string, as you did `as! String`. so you do this just before, as using a String value with sd_setimage URL wont work.

Comment: Does that make sense? It can get a bit confusing but firstly we are appending the name dictionary with the name and the correct url as a string. `self.namesWIthUrl[name] = profileImageUrl`. Then we access the dictionary with `let optionAUrl = URL.init(string: namesWithUrl[names[0]]` so that we have the correctly formatted URL value and by using the dictionary we know it is the correct url for that name and can use with `sd_setImage` using `optionAUrl` which is just `profileImageUrl` from the dictionary converted as a URL. so everything else stays the same.

Comment: If you wanted you could try doing `let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! URL` and changing the dict to `var namesWIthUrl = [String : URL]()`, and then you can skip the `let optionAUrl` step. But i'm not sure how well firebase plays with URL values.

Comment: Ah yes it has worked now! Except are images supposed to stack on top of each other? I have added an update ^ of how the simulator looks but would I be able to get it so you can swipe between the 4 images? you've saved me so much time i really appreciate it

Comment: @edey okay, that's great no problem!  Okay so you want one image in the scroll view visible and the rest underneath that you can scroll to? There are many different ways to do this, you might want to look at using a collectionView instead.

Comment: Yes so I was hoping i could scroll through the photos by swiping left and right

Comment: @edey you could also use just one ImageView, add a swipe gesture to it, and call `sd_setImage` on swipe to change the image, but that would not have an animation unless you built somthing

Comment: @edey try changing the constraints to the imageA starts on the scrollview left anchor, imageB left anchor is equal to image A, image C left anchor equal to image B etc, and make the images heights and widths equal to the scroll View height and width. and dont put a right anchor on image B, that might create the effect you are looking for

Comment: Okk perfect, i'm just doing that now - do you know how i would be able to make the size of the scroll view equal to the width of 4 photos - i've tried adding "        frame.origin.x = userImageScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat" and "frame.size = userImageScrollView.frame.size" and also "                    self.userImageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (self.userImageScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(namesWithUrl.count)), height: self.userImageScrollView.frame.size.height)"

Comment: I have added an edit in the code if you get the chance/wouldn't mind looking at it , thanks so much :)

Comment: Think the problem there is you are mixing AutoLayout with using `var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)` frames etc, these are different and can't be used together so you will have to choose. I personally prefer AutoLayout as in most cases, it makes adding constraints easier. If I answered your original question please accept as I think this would be better explained in another question specifically about layouts, I would be glad to help you further but I think we sorted out the main issue here so I would recommend making another question. (as it is getting very long here!)

Comment: @edey I'll do one more edit on my answer to explain the problem with your setupLayout()

Comment: Okk sure that makes sense, will try a little more but will ask another question if it still doesn't work - thank you!!

Comment: @edey have a look at my final edit, that explains how you should do your setupLayout() using AutoLayout. With testing it gives what you want, starts with the first image and then you scroll showing the next images, it may need a bit of tweaking with the constants etc to get the perfect fit. The only problem is it scrolls vertically as that is the normal use of a scrollView.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it but am still getting errors so i have posted another question as you mentioned since this was getting quite long! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984711/uiscrollview-or-uicollectionview-to-swipe-through-images-in-order-called-from-fi?noredirect=1#comment96727859_54984711) I'm thinking it might be worth considering changing to UICollectionView if it doesn't work and trying that way :)